# Avoiding scrolling up when developing in Go

Tags: go, developer-tools

Iam writing go and I am having 300 go routines running at the same time.

When one of them crashes the print log becomes incredibly long and I endup scrolling up every time (I only need to see the last line of my log and the first go routine failing).

How are you making your developer experience nicer in go?

Comment: Starting with Go 1.6 the traceback is shorter by default, are you using Go 1.6? https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetTraceback

Comment: Besides using the shorter tracebacks in go1.6, why are you panicking so often that this is an issue? (you can also just output to a file and read the top of the file if you want)

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of your program to a file

```
./program 2>&1 > log.txt
```

or to a program that lets you view the buffer head first

```
./program 2>&1 | less
```

The `2>&1` part combines stdout and stderr, so you get regular program output and error messages in the same buffer.